# Norm preserving isomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

I am really struggling here so i hope you can help me out.

Let $X_1 , X_2, Y$ be normed Vectorspaces and $L(X_1,X_2)$ be the vectorspace of continuous linear functions.

Show that

$\Phi: L(X_1,L(X_2,Y)) \longrightarrow L(X_2,L(X_1,Y)) \quad \text{with} \quad \Phi(A)x_1 := (x_2\longrightarrow A(x_2)x_1) $

is a norm preserving isomorphism.

Comment: I find subcripts rather confusing, it might be better to swap $x_1$ and $x_2$'s to indicate that they are from respective spaces. Other then that, any thoughts on problem?

Comment: I thought about this again and really didnt get far